# Calculate maximum velocity in order for the ball to "not slip"

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I was recently studying rolling without slipping, and I encountered some trouble. In order for a ball to roll without slipping, the force applied to the ball must follow the following inequality:

$$Fa < \mu s Fn$$

However, I was wondering if there is a maximum velocity that the ball must travel at in order to roll without slipping (on a completely flat surface). Is there such a velocity, and if so, how should I go about calculating this?

Answer (score 0):

On a ball undergoing pure rolling, the force you mentioned is the maximum force that can be applied at the centre of the ball for it to continue its motion without slipping. Applying a constant force applies a constant acceleration on a body. Here, ideally, the only thing that can cause slipping is force. So, if you keep the force constant and under the limit, the ball will never slip. Thus, there is no limit to the speed with which the ball can roll without slipping, within the frame of Newtonian Mechanics.